# How to get email from google oauth token in django allauth social login?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I am using allauth for social login(google) in REST API.If user is already registered with manual process and if the user tries google login with same email, response says "user already exists with this email". I want to know how to get the email address of that user from tha google access token so that i can take action furter.

Answer (score 1):

Django allauth has a view at `socialaccount_connections` which should allow a user that has already signed in using a local account to connect a third party app like google oauth.

Check out https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#social-connections-socialaccount-connections.

Then you can get to this page using this:

```html
<a href="{% url 'socialaccount_connections' %}">Connections</a>
```

You need to have the [connections](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/socialaccount/connections.html) template in your template folder.

Comment: Thank you for response! I want to implement this in API, but i am not able to do that.Can you help it to implement in API?

Comment: @Bhubanghimire, your best bet is to post another question, *with your code* for how you implemented social login.  The connections will probably be very similar.  And you'll also get more people to help.